# Error : "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NgnEngine"

Tags: ios, linker, clang

After looking in the internet for a solution for this error I found these solutions:

1. I make sure that the target is checked
2. I make sure that the file is in compile sources

I made it but still have the same error:

```
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NgnEngine", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a static library built for the device (armv7, armv7s architectures) and now you try to use it in the iPhone simulator that requires i386.

If that's the case, build it again for i386 or even better create a *fat* library with all the architectures.

You can check what architectures are included in the library with `lipo -info` in the command line.

Comment: thank you for quick answer, but i do not know how to create fat library

Comment: that's a different question; feel free to check this related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13264847/143097 (check my answer to it too, even if it's not the accepted one); also, search SO/Google for lipo howto or ios fat library