# Getting "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NgnEngine" error after linking iOS fat library

Tags: iphone, ios

Why i am still getting this error even after linking fat library

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NgnEngine", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and linking everything in "User-Defined

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am following the instruction which written here [Link ios-ngn-stak to your app](http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/wiki/Building_iDoubs_v2_x)
any help please, this is tiring me and it is my senior project

Comment: It seems that the library compiled for the simulator is built for 64-bit (x86_64) and not 32-bit (i386).

Comment: thank you for quick answer, but in your opinion what should I do

Comment: @AliAlahrani since this seems to be CPU-dependent: Apple certainly wants you to buy a newer Mac.

Comment: but their project work fine .. the problem it is when I want to link to my app

Comment: I mean in my devise work fine, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer this two link for getting solution if your issue:-

[Error : "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NgnEngine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886753/error-objc-class-ngnengine)

[Xcode with iOS - Creating a library in a way that is easy to run in debug mode, distribute, iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264847/xcode-with-ios-creating-a-library-in-a-way-that-is-easy-to-run-in-debug-mode)